# How do I get the html document size using javascript in a UIWebView

Tags: javascript, iphone, uiwebview

I'm trying to determine the size of the html document in a UIWebView.  window.innerWidth works on iOS4 but it doesn't work on iOS3 (wrong value).  document.documentElement.clientWidth isn't reliable on either.  Is there another way to use javascript to determine the width of the document (which should make the size of the webview in this case).

Comment: Why not use a percent for the width. Then you won't have to worry about the window's width.

Comment: I need to position things using javacsript

Answer (score 0):

That could work :

```
CGFloat currentWindowWidth = [[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.innerWidth"] floatValue];
```